# How to detect some unique browser instance number, or pid number per "window" or per "tab"

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a web app, and I have the classic problem that the session cookie is shared between browser instances, and browser tabs. Obviously the browser doesn't send back anything the header. However I am able to control all the requests inside the app, so I'm wondering if I can add my own "parameter".

So the question is, is there some JavaScript which might identify the process ID, or Instance ID, or Tab ID on the client side? I can take care of sending it to the server, but I'm wondering if anyone knows of any tricks on the browser side.

Browser-specific suggestions are welcome - I'm very happy with answers that will only work in one browser type.

Comment: You might want to look into sessionStorage. That is like localStorage but:"Opening a page in a new tab or window will cause a new session to be initiated, which differs from how session cookies work." See: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Comment: Btw, did you find another solution for your problem?

Answer (score 4):

Here is the list of information you can get from javascript: [Information about your Web Browser from Javascript](http://www.alanwood.net/demos/browserinfo.html). I don't think you can get system specific information like PIDs from javascript, it would certainly be a security issue.

Comment: You can now use RegEx to get the desired numbers.

Comment: @ToyDaVirus - RegEx to get numbers out of the information in Giaan's link? Or RegEx to get the Process ID number?

Comment: Going over I don't think its possible to get the Process ID from the Browser sting.

Answer (score 0):

sessionStorage might help you here.

http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/07/21/introduction-to-sessionstorage/

update:
`window.name` can be used.